# Has the incorporation of foreign phrases in English stopped?

Tags: history, loanwords

I know English contains many words taken directly from another language - *chauffeur*, for example - but I am interested in foreign *phrases*. These are phrases you'd see in writing or spoken aloud, such as:

- C'est la vie
- Caveat emptor
- Hasta la vista

Have there been any recent foreign language additions to the lexicon in recent history, say the past 50 years or so?

Comment: Something icelandic, like IKEA

Comment: I'd even add that my wife is a Spanish Translator and she has noticed from the official spanish source (can't remember the website) that several words that used to have a uniquely Spanish word have been removed and now the "official" spanish word is the english word.

Comment: Off the top of my head, from non-romance languages we have *l'chaim*, *domo arigato*, and *sturm und drang*.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I'm not sure it fits with the format of SE--it'd be a great topic for discussion, though. Maybe you could bring this up in chat?

Comment: By the way, I think you mean a *romance* language, not a *romantic* language.

Comment: From Swahili we have *hakuna matata*.

Comment: I see no problem with this question. It is about etymology. Somebody could have documented whether in the last 50 years or so, foreign phrases entered the English language.

Comment: @Theta30: This is not about Etymology. Anyway, words and expressions get incorporated, some get lost, others become standard language, etc, and this happens _all the time_. I don't think there is a moment in history where there is 0 (read _zero_) movement in that sense; sometimes it's less, sometimes it's more, but it's not zero.

Comment: @Alenanno ,etymology is *the study of the history of words, their origins*, here being the recent history. I agree with the other things, but you could have argued properly in an answer, not in a comment.

Comment: @Theta30: I can't actually, the answer is closed... If it gets reopened, I'm going to post an answer. :)

Comment: @Scott Mitchell: Are you interested in one that originated apparently 50/51 years ago?

Answer (score 4):

> Hasta la vista

Probably introduced about 10 years ago by the great actor and public orator of the age Mr A. Schwarzenegger

Comment: "Hasta la vista, baby" was a script catchphrase in a Schwarzenegger film of 20 years ago, but that very phrase was used in an earlier hit song (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasta_la_vista,_baby)).  The simpler phase "hasta la vista" was common in English long before those uses.

Comment: @mgkrebbs - you're right Terminator2 was 1991 - now I really feel old! But it was probably this that made the phrase popular and it was in the last 50years

Answer (score 1):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has about 1800 new (and revised) words added June 2011.  Including many of foreign origin.  Here is one: **babalaas** from Afrikaans, meaning *hangover*.

Comment: I've never heard that commonly used, though

Comment: I'm interested in foreign *phrases*, not individual words.

Comment: OK, newly-added phrases include: "Appellation d'Origine Contrôlée" and "croque madame".

Comment: @GEdgar: Are there any others? Is there a way I can see these or do you need a subscription?